# Why does the convergence radius even exist for power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, power-series

*WHY do power series diverge outside of the convergence radius? *Or:* Why does the convergence radius for power series even exist?*

Comment: Try plugging in an $|x|<1$ for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and then try with $|x|\ge1$ for a simple example

Comment: "Now $0$ is actually very far from the actual $f(x)$" - You're supposed to look at the _sum_ of all terms up to the $n$th term, not the $n$th term alone. $$(x-1)^3=-1+3x-3x^2+1x^3+0x^4+0x^5+0x^6+\cdots+0x^n.$$ This equation is true for all $n\geq3$, and it converges correctly to $(x-1)^3$ as $n\to\infty$. The zeroes are not a problem.

Comment: you're right! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a sufficient answer because this is more of a long comment, so feel free to say it doesn't help or downvote it.

I will answer based on what seems to be your question, "What is the deal with the radius of convergence? What is the intuition behind it?" Note this will not be rigorous at all.

You can wonder whether there is some predictability just by looking at the equation before you can go through the Ratio/Root Test methods, so let's take a few examples.

Notice that $\sin(x), \cos(x),$ and $e^x$ have no singularities where the functions are not defined, and each has a radius of convergence of $\infty$. But a function like $\log(a+x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=-a$. So perhaps a radius of convergence of $a$ makes sense because the length from the center point to the vertical asymptote is $a$.

This idea does not necessarily work for a function like $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, though. Clearly, that function has no vertical asymptotes, yet when centered at $x=1$, its Taylor series has a radius of convergence of $\sqrt{2}$. To understand this visually, we have to think about the complex plane. Notice that $1+x^2 = 0$ yields the set of solutions $x \in \left\{i,-i\right\}$. Those two elements are the singularities of the function. At $x=1$, the singularities are a distance of $\sqrt{2}$ away.

In general, instead of "moving in opposite directions" along the real line trying to find singularities, we need to "move in all directions" along the complex plane looking for singularities. And when you "hit" a singularity, the length of that radius would tell you the radius of convergence, which is why it is called the "radius" of convergence. The largest circle centered at $c$ such that the power series converges at each point inside is called the radius of convergence of the series, which we can denote as $|z-c| = R_0$, where $R_0$ is the radius of convergence. And in general, the set of all points inside some circle centered at $c$ is a region of convergence for the power series, if we are supposing the series converges at some point other than $c$.

This is not the full story, of course. You can extend the disc until you reach a point where the function is not holomorphic. And there are also removable singularities that can come into play, too. But for basic functions like the ones I mentioned, the idea works.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure to share some insight. @2GR8

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the following *not* entirely obvious property: if a power series $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n$ converges at a number $x_0$ then it converges at all $x$ with $|x| < |x_0|$, so it converges on $(-x_0,x_0]$ (and maybe not $-x_0$). So it is in the nature of power series to converge on intervals, with or without some of the endpoints.

For example, suppose we know $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n$ converges at $x = 1$. Then it converges on $(-1,1]$. Next, suppose we find out it also converges at $x = -2$. Then it converges on $[-2,2)$. The interval of converges might get bigger, but certainly not smaller.

If a power series does *not* converge at some number $c$ then it does not converge at any $x$ with $|x| > |c|$ (because if it converged at such $x$ it would converge at all smaller numbers in absolute value, and that includes $c$ where we're told it doesn't converge).

Ultimately what this means is the domain of convergence, if it is not all of $\mathbf R$, will be some symmetric interval of the form $(-R,R)$ with or without one of the endpoints $\pm R$. This can be made precise using the notion of a supremum: if $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbf R$ such that whenever a number $x_0$ is in $S$ we have $x \in S$ for all $x$ with $|x| < |x_0|$, and $S$ is not all of $\mathbf R$, then $(-R,R) \subset S \subset [-R,R]$ where $R = \sup_{x \in S} |x|$.

As a contrast to this, consider another important infinite series expansion: the Fourier series $a_0 + \sum_{n \geq 1} (a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx))$. If you are told this series converges at a number $x_0$, you do *not* learn anything about where else the series converges.  Convergence of Fourier series is a very delicate issue.  There is no simple description of the set of numbers at which a *general* Fourier series converges, although there are some sufficient conditions for convergence of suitably well-behaved periodic functions. The many subtle problems connected with understanding convergence of Fourier series led to a huge amount of mathematics in the 19th and early 20th centuries: the meaning of convergence, the definition of a function, Riemann's definition of his integral, measure theory, Cantor's work on set theory, and so on.  That is why David Bressoud chose to begin his historically-oriented account of real analysis (*A Radical Approach to Real Analysis*) by starting with a chapter on Fourier series as a "crisis in mathematics".  Srivastava's article [here](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/019/11/0977-0999) explains how Cantor's work on Fourier series (or "trigonometric series" in the old language) inspired his discoveries in set theory.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the fact that geometric series have a radius of convergence and that we can compare a power series to a geometric series:

Consider the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n$. If we can find $r \in [0, 1)$ and $N \geq 1$ such that $|a_n| \leq r^n$ for $n \geq N$, then by comparison with the geometric sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}r^n < \infty$, we will have $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|a_n| = \sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1}|a_n| + \sum_{n = N}^{\infty}r^n < \infty$, which is absolute convergence of our sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|a_n|$. Hence if there exists $r \in [0, 1)$ and $N \geq 1$ such that $\sup_{n \geq N}|a_n|^{1/n} \leq r$, then $\sum_{n}|a_n|$ converges absolutely. This is equivalent to saying that if $\limsup_{n}|a_n|^{1/n} < 1$, then $\sum_{n}|a_n|$ converges absolutely.

Moreoever, if $\limsup_{n}|a_n|^{1/n} = 1 + h > 1$, then $\sup_{k \geq n}|a_k|^{1/k} \geq 1 + h$ for all $n \geq 1$, so $|a_n| \geq (1 + h)^n$ for infinitley many $n$, and thus $\sum_{n}a_n$ does not converge.

If you apply the above to the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_nx^n$, then you get that if $\limsup_{n}|b_n|^{1/n}|x| < 1$, the series converges absolutely, and if $\limsup_{n}|b_n|^{1/n}|x| > 1$, the series diverges. In other words, the series has radius of convergence $R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n}|b_n|^{1/n}}$.